# How to overwrite an address with "\x00"

Tags: security, assembly, buffer-overflow, exploit

I'm trying to overwrite an address with buffer overflow.

The original address is `0x7fffffffddf0` and I want to overwrite this address and call the function which has an address of `0x400577`.

However, if I give an input as `"A x *n*" + "\x77\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00"`,

the address becomes `7fff00400577`, instead of `000000400577`.

It seems that \x00 is ignored.

I know that \x00 means NULL, but how can I write with \x00 in this case?

Comment: Typically this is because the NUL byte is the end-of-string mark in C and programs that copy strings often stop at the first NUL byte.

Comment: Yes, but the program says that 0x00007fff00400577 isn't avaiable.
```0x00007fff00400577 in ?? ()```
I want to just call the function whose address is ```0x0000000000400577```.
Is there any way?

Comment: Oh wait, try adding four more NUL bytes to overwrite the high four bytes of the return address.

Comment: More than ```\x77\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00```? Like ```\x77\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00```?

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: If you already do that, then indeed the issues is that whatever overflow you try to exploit stops copying your data at the first NUL byte; see how you write three NUL bytes but only one is copied over.

Comment: There isn't a way that always works.  Overwriting return addresses on x86-64 is sometimes harder than 32-bit x86 for this reason.

Comment: So nobody knows how to overwrite address with zero bytes in x64?